# What is the best way to make feature map bigger with zero padding in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am making a new model and this model is using CNN. And one layer whose feature map size is 32x32 gets input from feature maps with size of both 64x64 and 16x16. I can make 64x64 FM to become 33x32 size by pooling. But how can I make 16x16 sized FM to become 32x32 size?

Since the 32x32 FM layer gets 64x64 FM and 16x16 sized FM as inputs, my stratege is to make both 64x64 and 16x16 to become 32x32 sized FMs. And then concatenate them to use input to 32x32 sized FM layer. I know pooling makes 64x64 to 32x32. But I am not sure how to make 16x16 to be 32x33. I think zero padding would work, but I could not find appropriate function. What function should I use? Or is ther better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do basic upsampling or convolved upsampling.

```
#upsampling example
tf.image.resize_images(input, [32,32], method=ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)

#convolved example
tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input, [h,w, out_ch, input_channels], [batch_size, 32,32, out_ch], strides=[1,2,2,1])
```